# Относительный путь к локальной БД C#

Tags: c#

Уже неоднократно задаваемый вопрос, но ни в одном разделе не могу найти решения.
Точно также файл БД лежит в директории приложения, строка подключения с абсолютным путём:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
AttachDbFilename=F:\Порча\demos\TakeYourChain\TakeYourChain
\ReferenceDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Если использовать такое:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ReferenceDatabase.mdf;Integrated
Security=True";,
```

то данные оттуда вытаскиваются, но обновление БД с помощью SqlDataAdapter+SqlCommandBuilder не выполняется. Различные вариации пути перепробовал, но ничего не помогает.

```
var path = ...
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

Натыкался на такой вариант, но не понял, как им воспользоваться...
Так как же мне сделать всё-таки своё приложение портативным..?

Comment: ещё и код не отформатировался тут...

Comment: "...AttachDbFilename="+ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +"\ReferenceDatabase.mdf...". Чтобы перейти на папку выше в путь добавьте "..\ReferenceDatabase.mdf" или "..\..\ReferenceDatabase.mdf" на 2 уровня

Comment: @guitarherov "обновление БД с помощью SqlDataAdapter+SqlCommandBuilder не выполняется" - на самом деле все выполняется, просто |DataDirectory| - это папка bin, а не папка вашего проекта. Студия при каждом билде берет базу (которая наверняка у вас в проект добавлена) и копирует в папку bin, перетирая изменения. Поменяйте в свойствах файла базы Copy Always на Copy if newer.

Comment: @guitarhero если вдруг не угадал, и при запуске программы напрямую из bin данные тоже не сохраняются - скажите, я переоткрою вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash, если её не копировать, то тогда исключение "при попытке прикрепить базу к файлу с таким путём ошибка. типа база с таким именем существует, или описанная база не может быть открыта". Это с |DataDirectory|.

Comment: @user2455111 Если использовать AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, то "..\.." не работает... Может как-то можно сделать, чтоб не парсить строку посимвольно?

Comment: @guitarhero "парсить строку посимвольно" а зачем вы парсите строку посимвольно? Вы бы код привели, чтобы увидеть как вы пытаетесь сделать. Ну если, что вот пост на английском сайте был уже  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833640/connection-string-with-relative-path-to-the-database-file

Comment: @user2455111, код выше у меня приведен. При таком же способе, как на английском сайте, данные в базе также не сохраняются. Вот мне нужно, чтобы на любом компьютере строился свой такой путь:      AttachDbFilename=F:\Порча\demos\TakeYourChain\TakeYourChain
\ReferenceDatabase.mdf

Comment: @guitarhero я не предлагаю "не копировать". надо выставить в  Copy if newer - тогда студия не будет копировать поверх измененной базы.

Comment: @guitarhero у вас данные выбираются, сохраняются, но перетираются при перезапуске приложения из студии. Значит с путем к базе у вас проблем нет. Значит " Различные вариации пути" вам ничем не помогут. Оставьте |DataDirectory|\ReferenceDatabase.mdf, выставьте  Copy if newer и все заработает.

Comment: @PashaPash, всё, так действительно работает. спасибо!)) бессонная ночь даёт о себе знать...